# Jtable/JScrollPanel won't refresh (update data)

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, tablemodel

I have setup a `JTable` with paging - which works very well, but I have a problem with updating data to the table. table.repaint() is not working. Here is the code that I am using. Thanks in advance!

```
String[][] data = new String[100][4];

 String[] columnNames = new String[]{
         "IP", "PC_NAME", "ttl", "db"};
```

Constructor:

```
gui(){
    JTable table =  new JTable(data, columnNames);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    JButton next = new JButton("next");
    JButton prev = new JButton("prev");
    next.addActionListener(this);
    prev.addActionListener(this);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.add(prev);
    buttonPanel.add(next);
    panel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    panel.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    getContentPane().add(panel);}
```

ActionListener:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 if (e.getActionCommand() == "next") {
     Rectangle rect = scrollPane.getVisibleRect();
     JScrollBar  bar = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
     int blockIncr = scrollPane.getViewport().getViewRect().height;
     bar.setValue(bar.getValue() + blockIncr);
     scrollPane.scrollRectToVisible(rect);
 }
 if (e.getActionCommand() == "prev") {
     Rectangle rect = scrollPane.getVisibleRect();
     JScrollBar  bar = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
     int blockIncr = scrollPane.getViewport().getViewRect().height;
     bar.setValue(bar.getValue() - blockIncr);
     scrollPane.scrollRectToVisible(rect);
 }}
```

Here is the function that store data into an array:

```
int i=0;
public void WriteMonitorData (String IP, String PC_NAME, String ttl, String gw)
{
    data[i][0]=IP;
    data[i][1]=PC_NAME;
    data[i][2]=ttl;
    data[i][3]=gw;
    i++;
    table.repaint();
    scrollPane.repaint();

}
```

**Edit 1:**

I tried with DefaultTableModel and still no luck. Here is code that I used for updating table.
Constructor code didn't changed.
Declaration:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 String[][] data = new String[100][4];

 String[] columnNames = new String[]{
         "IP", "PC_NAME", "ttl", "db"};



            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,columnNames);
    JTable table =  new JTable(model);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
```

Here is function that updated table:

```
 public void WriteMonitorData (String IP, String PC_NAME, String ttl, String gw)
{

    System.out.println(IP);
    model.setValueAt(IP, i, 0);
    model.setValueAt(PC_NAME, i, 1);
    model.setValueAt(ttl, i, 2);
    model.setValueAt(gw, i, 3);
    i++;
    model.fireTableDataChanged();
    table.repaint();
    scrollPane.repaint();

}
```

Comment: Please clean up your code indentation. All code on the same block should be uniformly indented (I like 3 spaces myself). If you don't do this, you are making it more difficult than it needs to be for a volunteer to review and understand your code and this really isn't fair to us.

Comment: Also please spend a little time and describe the details of your problem. We certainly can't run this code fragment and so if you don't post compilable code, you need to give us enough information for us to be able to make reasonable guesses as to the source of the problem. This will require information supplied by **you**.

Comment: I have other class that call function WriteMonitorData  and pass 4 strings. When function WriteMonitorData  is called I stored passed string to variable data that contains data for table. Problem is that table data doesn't refresh. I successfully store passed string to variable data but for some reason table rows are empty

Comment: See edit to answer. Use a DefaultTableModel to hold the JTable's data, and edit its data.

Comment: I tried with DefaultTableModel and still no luck. Can you tell me what did I do wrong ?

Comment: Not really since I can't run or compile your code. Consider putting in the effort to create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org) (check out the link) as this would allow us to run your code without being drowned in unrelated code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your comparing Strings with `==`. Use the `equals(...)` method instead.

- `==` compares if two variables refer to the same object -- something you don't care about. Thus two String variables can hold the same word but not be deemed equal by this operation.
- the `equals(...)` or `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method checks if two String variables hold the same chars in the same order, and that you **do** care about.

So not:

```
if (e.getActionCommand() == "next") {
  //  ...
}
```

but rather:

```
if ("next".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
  //  ...
}
```

or if you don't care about case:

```
if ("next".equalsIgnoreCase(e.getActionCommand())) {
  //  ...
}
```

**Edit 1**
Next, once your JTable has hold of the data, changing the data will likely have no effect on the JTable. So here you change the data array:

```
int i=0;
public void WriteMonitorData (String IP, String PC_NAME, String ttl, String gw)
{
    data[i][0]=IP;
    data[i][1]=PC_NAME;
    data[i][2]=ttl;
    data[i][3]=gw;
    i++;
    table.repaint();
    scrollPane.repaint();

}
```

But this array has already been passed into the JTable, is now part of its model and has been changed into a Vector in all likelihood.

To see a change in your JTable's representation of the data, you must change the data held by the table's ***model***. I suggest that you use a DefaultTableModel to hold your data in the JTable and then in your method above (which should begin with a lower case letter), you change the data held by the model.

Also, regardless if your `if` blocks work or not, don't use `==` to compare Strings as this will bite you, if not now, soon.

Comment: @user1336646: then please do tell us what *isn't* working fine. The details *are* very important.

Comment: Action listeners are working fine. problem is that table data is not refreshing/updating...

Comment: @user1336646: see edit. you're changing the wrong data likely. And still, get rid of `==` with Strings regardless if it's "working fine".

Comment: Thanks for replays guys. I am going to try with DefaultTableModel. Will post back results. Thanks for help